# Distribute brochures to sales force

Tags: cloud-service, documentation-viewer

I am looking for a solution to distribute product brochures in about 26 languages to members of the world-wide sales force.

I wrote an application around 15 years ago but this is in desperate need of attention so I am wondering if there are any 'standard solutions' out there.

Current features:

- Documents organised by language/country by marketing department and updated quarterly
- An index is created by scanning the documents allowing a search function on the client side
- A web application serves documents to client application
- End-users alerted to new documents
- End-users can choose one or more groups to synchronise to their local machine allowing offline access
- Download statistics are gathered for report generation
- View statistics would be good but not currently implemented
- All documents are PDF. All clients on Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

I may not have the best solution but seeing that you're yet to get any bites, you may want to consider a cloud storage option.

I work with [ExaVault](https://www.exavault.com/) which is a cloud-based FTP server that provides many options for connecting and circulating data. If your application can make an FTP connection and/or leverage our APIs, this could be a great solution.

When you create an account, you will have the the following features:

- *Documents organized by language/country by marketing department and updated quarterly.* The marketing team can be assigned users with specific permissions to access and update folders
- *End-users alerted to new documents.* Custom notifications can be set on all folders.
- *Download statistics are gathered for report generation.* A detailed Session Log is provided for all activity.

The following can be set-up through use of an FTP Client, connecting with custom scripts or using our APIs:

- *An index is created by scanning the documents allowing a search function on the client side.* We have a fully documented API that can be used.
- *A web application serves documents to client application.* We also have very user friendly sharing options that can be accessed from any browser.

The items that might require some significant effort or require a workflow from a FTP Client connection:

- *End-users can choose one or more groups to synchronize to their local machine allowing offline access.* There is the option create public "Share" links to access specific folders but this would not allow for syncing with a local machine - instead capturing from a browser.

No view statistics for specific files at this time but delivery receipts to for when shared files and folders are accessed.

In addition to the above, you'll have a lot of options for user permissions, security options, and our support team to help you get set up.

Best of luck!